# Is there an easier way to work with lists of base types

Tags: vb.net, list, generics, narrowing

I have a list of a base class `List(Of Person)` which contains variables which are sub classes `Employee` and `Manager`

I want to call `SetName` on each person in the list but vb.net doesnt pick the narrowest overloaded `SetName` function. Is there a way to automatically pick the narrowest `SetName` function automatically? Here is my example code

```
Module Example
    Class Person
        Public Name As String
    End Class

    Class Employee
        Inherits Person
        Public EmployeeID As String
    End Class

    Class Manager
        Inherits Person
        Public ManagerID As String
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim PersonList As New List(Of Person)
        Call PersonList.Add(New Employee)
        Call PersonList.Add(New Manager)

        For Each CurrentPerson As Person In PersonList
            Call SetName(CurrentPerson)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetName(AnyManager As Manager)
        AnyManager.Name = "Manager Tom"
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetName(AnyEmployee As Employee)
        AnyEmployee.Name = "Employee Bob"
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetName(AnyPerson As Person)
        AnyPerson.Name = "Person Jim"
    End Sub
End Module
```

everyone in the list ends up as "Person Jim" but i want the first `Employee` to be "Employee Bob" and the second `Manager` to be "Manager Tom"

Is this the cleanest way to do so? This is the only way i could think to do it. This will get messy in my case because I have around 20 derived classes instead of 2.

```
For Each CurrentPerson As Person In PersonList
    If TypeOf (CurrentPerson) Is Employee Then
        Call SetName(CType(CurrentPerson, Employee))
    ElseIf TypeOf (CurrentPerson) Is Manager Then
        Call SetName(CType(CurrentPerson, Manager))
    End If
Next
```

Edit: I think I failed to make my needs more clear. Setname was just meant to be a standin for any function that needs the narrow types in the list and not the base class. The actual names are not important. Maybe I should have used an example where the function actually messes with the employee ID and manager ID. Sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: You could use polymorphism instead of inheritance.

Comment: ah that might be where i went wrong. I thought inheritance was automatically polymorphism since they all got the Name property. Do I use Implements instead of inherits?

Comment: It's a really bad idea to add 'whatever' to a property just for the sake of 'anything', instead I would override `ToString` to do that.

Comment: That would work, but if your real use is as simple as your example, please consider @Aybe suggestion to overrive `ToString`. I hadn't though of it but it's a sound idea.

Comment: my real case is considerable more complex but follows the same lines. I just want to be able to pass varibles from my ```List(Of Person)``` while preserving the narrow type that i added to the list and not the base class type.

Comment: You can make `Person` a `MustInherit` (abstract) class, then use a single `Public Sub SetName(Of T As Person)(AnyOne As T)` and evaluate `AnyOne` inside that method.

Comment: @R.Binter Yes, implements it is then.

Comment: @Jimi That seems like a decent idea. Is the best way to evaluate the type of ```AnyOne``` just to do a case select on the type? Then it would also eliminate all the casts because the variables will be passed in with their narrowest types?

Comment: Since you have multiple choices base on the concrete type, you can `Select Case AnyOne.GetType()` or use a Dictionary or have the type itself provide a default value for a/the Propert(y/ies). What you do is determined by the actual implementation. Since you have provided just a symbolic representation of what your code *should* do, you will probably receive generic suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

No sure what you are looking for but the following code gets the names you are asking for. I got rid of the SetName subs and set the name property in the constructor of the class. You could make a paramertized constructor to set different names. BTW, the Call statement is not required in most circumstances.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim PersonList As New List(Of Person)
    PersonList.Add(New Employee)
    PersonList.Add(New Manager)

    For Each CurrentPerson In PersonList
        Debug.Print(CurrentPerson.Name)
    Next
End Sub

Class Employee
    Inherits Person
    Public EmployeeID As String
    Public Sub New()
        Name = "Employee Bob"
    End Sub
End Class

Class Manager
    Inherits Person
    Public ManagerID As String
    Public Sub New()
        Name = "Manager Tom"
    End Sub
End Class

Class Person
    Public Name As String
    Public Sub New()
        Name = "Person Jim"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Code using your SetName subs and no parametized constructor...

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim PersonList As New List(Of Person)
    Dim e As New Employee()
    SetName(e)
    PersonList.Add(e)
    Dim m As New Manager()
    SetName(m)
    PersonList.Add(m)

    For Each CurrentPerson In PersonList
        Debug.Print(CurrentPerson.Name)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub SetName(AnyManager As Manager)
    AnyManager.Name = "Manager Tom"
End Sub

Public Sub SetName(AnyEmployee As Employee)
    AnyEmployee.Name = "Employee Bob"
End Sub

Public Sub SetName(AnyPerson As Person)
    AnyPerson.Name = "Person Jim"
End Sub

Class Employee
    Inherits Person
    Public EmployeeID As String
End Class

Class Manager
    Inherits Person
    Public ManagerID As String
End Class

Class Person
    Public Name As String
End Class
```

Both codes produce...

```
Employee Bob
Manager Tom
```

in the Immediate window